# how can i fix a bug in kivy class

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hi i have a problem with python code and library Kivy.
I have a start my code

```
from kivy.app import App
class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

and then i see error

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Amir\.kivy\logs\kivy_22-06-02_18.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.2
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Amir\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 16:30:00) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Amir\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "PythonApplication1.py", line 7, in <module>
     MyApp.run()
 TypeError: run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `MyApp().run()`, not `MyApp.run()`: `run` is a method of the App class so you need to create an instance of the App class before you can call it.